# replace values in a column with values ordered

Tags: r

I have a data.frame that looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(names=c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K"), 
                 values=c(1,1,4,6,7,7,7,9,9,14,15))
```

And I would like something similar to this:

```
df <- data.frame(names=c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K"), 
                 values=c(1,1,2,3,4,4,4,5,5,6,7))
```

I know it is a silly question but I don't know how to do it. Thanks

Note: the values in the second data.frame should be order from 1 to n

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `cumsum`:

```
df <- transform(df, values = cumsum(c(1, head(values, -1) != tail(values, -1))))
```

Another version that might be easier to understand, but a little slower I would guess:

```
df<- transform(df, values = cumsum(c(1, diff(values) != 0))
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that `df$values` is sorted, another way would be to use `table`.

```
tt <- table(df$values)
rep(seq_along(tt), tt)
# [1] 1 1 2 3 4 4 4 5 5 6 7
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to convert to factor and extract the ordering from there:

```
df$values = as.numeric(as.factor(df$values))
```